# Which eschatological belief does Catholicism profess? Deem heretical?

Tags: catholicism, eschatology

There are a variety of eschatological beliefs in Christianity, such as Premillennialism, Amillennialism, etc. Which eschatological belief does Catholicism profess, if any, and which eschatological belief(s) does Catholicism deem heretical, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Decree of the Holy Office, July 21, 1944, on Millenarianism (Chiliasm):

> [22](http://patristica.net/denzinger/#n2200)96 In recent times on several occasions this Supreme Sacred Congregation of the Holy Office has been asked what must be thought of the system of mitigated Millenarianism, which teaches, for example, that Christ the Lord before the final judgment, whether or not preceded by the resurrection of the many just, will come visibly to rule over this world. The answer is: The system of mitigated Millenarianism cannot be taught safely.